# updating boost.python code to new API without numeric.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to compile [pyBKT](https://github.com/CAHLR/pyBKT) project and it uses `boost::python` library which significantly changed in version 1.63, when `boost/python/numeric.hpp` was removed. I updated it to `boost/numpy.hpp` as suggested, but I am having trouble updating other parts of the code to the new API.

In particular, I'm having trouble with the following code which wraps results into `numpy` objects.

```
//wrapping results in numpy objects.
npy_intp all_stateseqs_dims[2] = {1, bigT}; 
PyObject * all_stateseqs_pyObj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, all_stateseqs_dims, NPY_INT, all_stateseqs); 
boost::python::handle<> all_stateseqs_handle( all_stateseqs_pyObj );
boost::python::numpy::ndarray all_stateseqs_handle_arr( all_stateseqs_pyObj );

npy_intp all_data_dims[2] = {num_subparts, bigT}; 
PyObject * all_data_pyObj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, all_data_dims, NPY_INT, all_data); 
boost::python::handle<> all_data_handle( all_data_pyObj );
boost::python::numpy::ndarray all_data_arr( all_data_handle );
```

the reported error is

```
generate/synthetic_data_helper.cpp:161:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::python::numpy::ndarray::ndarray(boost::python::handle<>&)’
```

I understand that it means that the constructor with this parameter can't be found but I don't know how to change it as I'm not a C++ programer.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the numpy API directly, as I have to support back to Numpy 1.4 (RHEL6 default, sigh).  It turns out to not be too bad, you just return a new object.  This presumes you've already exposed an image object:

```
// accessor to wrap data from image up into read-only numpy array
//
static inline object image_get_data(object &imageobj) {
    // extract image base
    const image &img = extract<const image&>(imageobj);

    // build read-only array around data
    npy_intp dims[2] = {img.width, img.height};
    PyObject* array = PyArray_New(
        &PyArray_Type, 2, dims, NPY_COMPLEX64, NULL, (void*)img.data(), 0,
        NPY_ARRAY_C_CONTIGUOUS | NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED, NULL
    );

    // increment reference to image object and set base pointer
    // of array, this will establish an ownership link so that
    // image instance won't be destroyed before the array.
    incref(image.ptr());
    NPY_SET_BASE(array, image.ptr());
    return object(handle<>(array));
}
```

Which is then added to the image object as:

```
 .add_property("data", &image_get_data, "read-only numpy array containing image data")
```